# Why isn't my Cocoa selector actually being called?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, debugging, breakpoints

I'm stumped. I don't have any errors or even warnings. I set a breakpoint at the line that calls it, and the program stops there, but when I set a breakpoint inside the actual code for that selector, the program doesn't stop. The selector I'm concerned with is `toggleCellAtX:Y:`. Here's SPPuzzle.m:

```
#import "SPPuzzle.h"

@implementation SPPuzzle

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        int x, y;
        for (y=0; y<3; y++)
            for (x=0; x<3; x++) {
                cells[x][y] = FALSE;
            }
    }

    return self;
}

- (BOOL)cellOnAtX:(int)x Y:(int)y {
    return cells[x][y];
}

- (void)toggleCellAtX:(int)x Y:(int)y {
    cells[x][y] = !cells[x][y];  // Breakpoint here doesn't stop program.
}

@end
```

And here's SPPuzzleView.m:

```
#import "SPPuzzleView.h"

@implementation SPPuzzleView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        puzzleInstance = [[SPPuzzle alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    int x, y;

    for (y=0; y<3; y++)
        for (x=0; x<3; x++) {
            if ([puzzleInstance cellOnAtX:x Y:y]) {
                [[NSColor greenColor] set];
            } else {
                [[NSColor redColor] set];
            }

            [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSMakeRect(100*x, 100*y, 100, 100)] fill];
            [[NSColor blackColor] set];
            [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSMakeRect(100*x, 100*y, 100, 100)] stroke];
        }
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    int x = (int)[theEvent locationInWindow].x / 100;
    int y = (int)[theEvent locationInWindow].y / 100;

    [puzzleInstance toggleCellAtX:x Y:y];  // Breakpoint here does stop program.
    [self setNeedsDisplay:TRUE];
}

@end
```

I added comments to show where the breakpoints are. What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I used Step Into on the invocation of the method, but it just goes to the next line (`[self setNeedsDisplay:TRUE];`).

Comment: Verify that `puzzleInstance` is not `nil`. This is likely to happen if your view is instantiated from a xib because IIRC it calls `initWithCoder:` then `awakeFromNib` instead of `initWithFrame:`. It's a long shot, but if it works, just tell and I'll repost it as an answer.

Comment: @zneak This is not a long shot, it's nearly certainly the problem.

Comment: Yep, it's nil all right, which I assume is what 0x0 in the watch list means. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`puzzleInstance` is probably `nil` (`0x0` in the watch list, as you noted: `nil` is just another fancy name for the memory address `0`). This would be the case if you instantiated your `SPPuzzleView` from a XIB file, because the loading mechanism calls `initWithCoder:` (then `awakeFromNib`) instead of `initWithFrame:`, leaving your `puzzleInstance` uninitialized.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks! Just wondering though: why wouldn't the program have crashed with a segfault or whatever? Also, that seems like an easy-enough mistake to make that there should be a warning for it.

Comment: That is the specification of ObjectiveC. When you call a method on `nil`, the method just returns `nil`. It becomes handy in a lot of situations when you get used to, and it actually is intuitive too in a sense like 0 times something is 0.

Comment: @flam2006, calling a method on `nil` will do nothing and return the zero-value of the method's return type. That is, if the value would be of a numeric type, you get 0 (this includes methods returning pointers); and if the value would be of a structure or union type, you would get a zero-filled structure.